# How can I select from two different columns for my search feature?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

So I created a database with two columns, Name and Info. Now for my search feature if user types something similar to info or name I want it to show on the screen. As of right now it only does one or the other I can't make it to do both. So I know the issue lies in my select method in database. As of right now it is set to like this:

now if I put "Info Like? " it shows the search based on the Info column and if I change that to "Name Like?" it shows the search based on Name column.

```
   public List<myList> getNameandInfo(String text) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


    //Column Name from database table
    String[] sqlSelect = {"Name", "Info"};
    String tableName = "Grocery"; // table name

    qb.setTables(tableName);

    //This line of code only shows result for Info column
 Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "Info LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + 
 text + "%"}, null, null, null);
    List<Mylist> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Mylist myList = new Mylist();

    myList.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));

    myList.setInfo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Info")));

            result.add(myList);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

//tried this line of code but it crashes the app
   Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, ("Name LIKE ?")+("Info LIKE ?"), new String[]{"%" + text + "%"}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `WHERE` part from:

```
("Name LIKE ?")+("Info LIKE ?")
```

to:

```
"Name LIKE ? AND Info LIKE ?"
```

or maybe you need `OR`?
Also for the arguments you need 2 strings, not only 1:

```
"%" + text + "%"
```

so change to something like this:

```
new String[]{"%" + text1 + "%", "%" + text2 + "%"}
```

If you have only 1 value to check for both Name and Info:

```
 new String[]{"%" + text + "%", "%" + text + "%"}
```

Comment: i did but it says i have less than 15 reputation so it wont show publicly. im sorry im a noob

Comment: @DavidKim you need to click the check mark to the left of my answer, not upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make use of OR in the query:

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, ("Name LIKE ? OR Info LIKE ?"), new String[]{"%" + text + "%"}, null, null, null);
```